# How to compute logarithmic loss with the probability output of binary classification

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, dataset

The following code are used to produce the probability output of binary classification with Random Forest.

```
library(randomForest) 

rf <- randomForest(train, train_label,importance=TRUE,proximity=TRUE)
prediction<-predict(rf, test, type="prob")
```

Then the result about prediction is as follows:

[image]

The true label about test data are known (named **test_label**).  Now I want to compute [logarithmic loss](http://www.r-bloggers.com/making-sense-of-logarithmic-loss/) for probability output of binary classification. The function about LogLoss is as follows.

```
LogLoss=function(actual, predicted)
{
  result=-1/length(actual)*(sum((actual*log(predicted)+(1-actual)*log(1-predicted))))
  return(result)
}
```

How to compute logarithmic loss with probability output of binary classification. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you already have everything you need, assuming you also have a vector of labels for the test set (call it `test_labels`). You can now just say `LogLoss(test_labels, prediction[,1])`.